# quotes and spaces in singularity container

Tags: bash, singularity-container

I am trying to send an argument from a terminal into a singularity container.  It am trying to run an AFNI container (19.3.18) https://afni.nimh.nih.gov/pub/dist/doc/htmldoc/background_install/container.html

I am working in a bash terminal and need the argument to look like this when it runs within the container.  No matter what I do, this keeps failing and I get an error saying that the program doesn't recognize "exc".

`'SYM: +exc -eq'`

The full code is listed below for reference.  Could someone please offer some suggestions?

I have tried the following...

```
-gltsym "SYM: +exc -eq"
-gltsym "'SYM: +exc -eq"
-gltsym "SYM: \"+exc -eq\""
-gltsym "SYM: \+exc \-eq"
storing the argument as a variable like here (as suggested below) https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, so prior to running the create the following variable... 
arg=("'SYM:\ +exc\ -eq'")

and then inserting the argument into the command like '''-gltsym"${args[@]}"

Still getting the error?


PORTION OF CODE THAT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM HIGHLIGHTED BY STARS BELOW
3dDeconvolve \
  -input /work/06953/jes6785/ls6/NECTARY_DATA/derivatives/fmriprep-v22.0.2/sub-b071/ses-01/func/sub-b071_ses01_task-cyb_dir-AP_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_6.0blur+scale.nii \
  -mask /work/06953/jes6785/ls6/NECTARY_DATA/derivatives/fmriprep-v22.0.2/sub-b071/ses-01/func/sub-b071_ses-01_task-soc_dir-AP_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-brain_mask.nii.gz \
  -polort A \
  -num_stimts 2 \
  -stim_times_AM1 1 /work2/06953/jes6785/ls6/NECTARY_DATA/derivatives/AFNI_Behavioral_Files/sub_b071/sub_071-1_tf_under_1.1D dmBLOCK\(2\) \
  -stim_label 1 exc \
  -stim_times_AM1 2  /work2/06953/jes6785/ls6/NECTARY_DATA/derivatives/AFNI_Behavioral_Files/sub_b071/sub_071-1_tf_equal_1.1D dmBLOCK\(2\) \
  -stim_label 2 eq \
  -ortvec /work2/06953/jes6785/ls6/NECTARY_DATA/derivatives/Confound_Files/sub_b071/sub_b071_conservative_confounds.txt \
  test \
  ***-gltsym 'SYM: +exc -eq' \***
  -glt_label 1 exc \
  -fout -tout \
  -x1D X.xmat.1D \
  -xjpeg 071X.jpg \
  -x1D_uncensored 071X.nocensor.xmat.1D \
  -fitts fitts.071 \
  -errts errtsSYM:exc-eqSYM:1-2.071 \
  -bucket stats.071
```

Comment: When you put `'SYM: +exc -eq'` on a command line, the quotes **don't become part of the command**; they're just instructions to the shell to hold things together.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you're storing your command _in a variable_ this all makes sense -- and you need to follow one of the solutions shown in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- but you need to show us enough context to make that determination.

Comment: Anyhow -- inside single quotes, _everything_ is literal, including both backslashes and spaces. Don't add extra backslashes inside single quotes unless they're actually part of your data.

Comment: (As BashFAQ #50 describes, quotes only serve their purpose of holding things together when you use them as _syntax_, not when you put them in data; we'd need a [mre] we can follow to see the problem ourselves to know which of those things you're doing).

Comment: @Charles Duffy tried to make some edits to address your questions and be a bit clearer.  I don't believe the issue is with the container, I think it's passing the argument into the container from bash that is causing issues.  I am sure this is an easy fix, but just can't figure it out.  Thank you again.

Comment: Don't do "highlighted by stars" in code samples here, btw. As you can see, it doesn't actually do any highlighting; code samples should be _literal code_ someone else can copy-and-paste to produce the same problem themselves, as described in the [mre] page in the Help Center.

Comment: And the thing you say you're doing in response to reading BashFAQ #50 is not _at all in any way_ what BashFAQ #50 is telling you to do.

Comment: Anyhow, backing up: Can you build an example someone else can run without changes to test their answers? Right now, only you and nobody else has all the data &c to run your `3dDeconvolve` command, so nobody can test their answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by putting double quotes around the entire thing... in two different places. In my case, we use a wrapper `afnirun` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apptainer run -B /data /singularity/afni.simg  "$@"
```

And then in the analysis script, we call:

```
afnirun "afni_proc.py -subj_id ${subj}.$task \
      -dsets $subj_dir/afni/${subj}_Run1.nii $subj_dir/afni/${subj}_Run2.nii $subj_dir/afni/${subj}_Run3.nii $subj_dir/afni/${subj}_Run4.nii \
      -scr_overwrite \

.
.
.

      -num_glt 3 \
      -gltsym 'SYM: NEG_LOOK -NEG_REG'   -glt_label 1 NEG_LOOK_v_REG \
      -gltsym 'SYM: NEG_REG -NEUT_LOOK'  -glt_label 2 NEG_REG_v_NEUT_LOOK \
      -gltsym 'SYM: NEUT_LOOK -NEG_LOOK' -glt_label 3 NEUT_LOOK_v_REG \
      -regress_reml_exec                                      \
.
.
.
      -html_review_style        pythonic                               \
      -execute"
```

Note the double quotes around `$@` in the wrapper script *and* around the *entire* `afni_proc.py` command line.